# the_author_meta() vs get_the_author_meta()

Tags: php

As far as I know, `the_author_meta()` automatically displays the data while `get_the_author_meta()` has to be `echo-d`, it can also be saved as variable and do something with it.

**Is there something else to it that is not documented in codex?**

Also, is one or the other function *heavier* or is there a third better alternative?

This is not the case of premature optimization - I need to dispay *a lot* of author data.

---

**References:**

[the_author_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_meta/)

[get_the_author_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the source code for [`the_author_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_meta/), it simply, in essence, just echo's the result from [`get_the_author_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/).

WordPress has quite a lot of functions where functions with a `the_*` prefix simply echos the results from its `get_*` counter parts. The `get_*` prefix is almost always used for functions which return its results.

There is really no performance differences between the two functions here, and you can use anyone to your liking, although each actually has each own specific use. Use `the_author_meta()` if you need to display the data, it looks a bit nutty to use `echo get_the_author_meta()`. Use `get_the_author_meta()` if you need to store the data for later use, or in shortcodes which require returned content

### EDIT

You can always look up the source code on https://developer.wordpress.org, something you should always do. Never ever take something for granted. Just an example of the above, `get_the_content()` return unfiltered, raw post content, `the_content` returns the filtered content from the `get_the_content()`, so they are vastly apart in what they do

### EDIT 2

> ....is there a third better alternative

If you look at the source code from `get_the_author_meta()`, it uses [`get_userdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/) which returns all the fields you might be interested in

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: Hmm, `get_userdata()` seems like the best solution in cases where you need to display most of the user data _(e.g profile page)_. Then it doesn't need to use all the other functions that seems like a waste of resources _(minor waste but still)_ and are just used to make programmer's life easier.

Comment: While `get_the_author_meta()` always uses `get_userdata()` and I always need to deal with more than one type of user data, I think I'll avoid `get_the_author_meta()` completely. That answers the question for me.

Answer (score 3):

With this sort of question, the simplest thing to do is to [look it up in Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) then follow the link to see [the function in source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/author-template.php#L113).

There we can see that `the_author_meta` just calls `get_the_author_meta` and passes the result through a filter.

```
function the_author_meta( $field = '', $user_id = false ) {
    $author_meta = get_the_author_meta( $field, $user_id );

    echo apply_filters( 'the_author_' . $field, $author_meta, $user_id );
}
```

Another important thing to note is that, like post metadata, when you request a single meta item, all of it is loaded and cached, so it doesn't really matter if you fetch one meta field or 50, it's just a single trip to the database to fetch it all in both cases.